# Finding eigen vectors using numpy.linalg.eig

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I want to find the eigen vector for a matrix. I am using the numpy.linalg.eig library in python. The output obtained from this command is not giving eigen vector in the vector form.

```
x = np.array([[0, 1], [-2, -3]])
val, vec=np.linalg.eig(x)
```

`vec` gives the output `array([[ 0.70710678, -0.4472136 ], [-0.70710678,  0.89442719]])`. And hence `vec[0]` and `vec[1]` are `[ 0.70710678, -0.4472136 ]` and `[-0.70710678,  0.89442719]` respectively.(These are not the eigen vectors for this matrix).

The eigen vectors for this matrix are `[0.70710678,-0.70710678]` and `[-0.4472136, 0.89442719]`.(which cannot be obtained from `vec[0]` or `vec[1]` as it is the transpose). How to get the actual eigen vectors from `vec` variable?

Comment: The documentation says that the result must be read in columns which is what you have: "The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]."

Comment: Thanks @Eskapp. I was able to get the column using vec[:,i].